# Como logro Insertar datos en tabla relacional PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Muy Buenas ... Sigo Intentando hasta aprender realizar preguntas en este prestigioso sitio. logré subir una imagen donde se visualizan tres tablas que espero estén bien relacionadas pero hasta el momento no logro hacer INSERT en la segunda ni en la tercera tabla, como lo podría hacer usando PHP con Mysqli  ? [image]

```
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `certificado`
--

CREATE TABLE `certificado` (
  `id_certifica` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `certi_nombre` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nombre del usuario Certificado',
  `certi_ced` int(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Cedula',
  `certi_curso` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Curso Certificado',
  `fecha_desde` date NOT NULL,
  `certi_ciudad` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_hasta` date NOT NULL,
  `certi_nivel` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nivel de Certificacion',
  `inte_horaria` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Intensidad de horas',
  `dia_firma` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Dia Firmado',
  `mes_firma` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mes Firmado',
  `factura_numero` int(120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Codigo de la Fatura',
  `estado` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Estado del Correo',
  `enviado` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Reporta envío de Correo',
  `cod_certifica` int(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Codigo Unico del Certificado',
  `fecha_registro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Fechas de Modificacion',
  `usuario` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `facturacion`
--

CREATE TABLE `facturacion` (
  `ingreso_cod` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `cliente` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Factura Generada a:',
  `oingreso` int(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Orden de Ingreso',
  `num_fac` int(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Numero o Consecutivo de factura',
  `estado_fac` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Estado de la Factura'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci COMMENT='Facturacion';

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `ingresos`
--

CREATE TABLE `ingresos` (
  `cod_ingreso` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` int(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Cedula',
  `nombre` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primer Nombre',
  `nombres` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Segundo Nombre',
  `apellido` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primer Apellido',
  `apellidos` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Segundo Apeliido',
  `tipo_ced` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tipo de Cedula',
  `genero` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `pais_nac` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `f_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo_sangre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `formacion` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `g_sangre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel_edu` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `sector` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `cargo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nivel_l_e` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_social` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `o_servicio_ext` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `empresa` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `empresa_temp` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `alergia` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `enfermedades` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `lesiones` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `medicamentos` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `n_contacto` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo_factura` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tipo de Factura',
  `tel_contacto` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `c_contacto` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `doc_cumple` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `text_cumple` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `imagen` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_modifica` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci COMMENT='Table de Ingresos';

-- Indices de la tabla `certificado`
--
ALTER TABLE `certificado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_certifica`),
  ADD KEY `factura_numero` (`factura_numero`),
  ADD KEY `factura_numero_2` (`factura_numero`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `facturacion`
--
ALTER TABLE `facturacion`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`num_fac`),
  ADD KEY `ingreso_cod` (`ingreso_cod`);

-- Indices de la tabla `ingresos`
--
ALTER TABLE `ingresos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cod_ingreso`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `cod_ingreso` (`cod_ingreso`);

-- Filtros para la tabla `certificado`
--
ALTER TABLE `certificado`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `certificado_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`factura_numero`) REFERENCES `facturacion` (`num_fac`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `facturacion`
--
ALTER TABLE `facturacion`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `facturacion_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ingreso_cod`) REFERENCES `ingresos` (`cod_ingreso`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Este es el codigo PHP que estoy usando para hacer el INSERT

```
    require("conect.php");

$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

  echo "No lograste conectarte ! VERIFICA";

  exit(); 
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encontró la Base de Datos");
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");


$insertar = "INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, cliente, oingreso, num_fac, estado_fac) VALUES (".$_POST['ingreso_cod']. ",'".$_POST['cliente']. "', ".$_POST['oingreso'].",".$_POST['num_fac'].",".$_POST['estado_fac'].")";

echo $insertar . "<br>";

$resultado = $mysqli->query($insertar);

if(!$resultado)
{
      echo "El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitido";
}
else{

  echo "El Ingreso de factura que realizó fue satisfactorio" ;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.  ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que no logras hacer `INSERT`?  ¿Qué código estás usando?  ¿Qué error o problema te está dando?

Comment: A.Cedano y a para toda la comunidad. Este es el codigo que intento usar el cual es un INSERT normal. 
$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

  echo "No lograste conectarte ! VERIFICA";

  exit(); 
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encontró la Base de Datos");
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");


$insertar = "INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, cliente, oingreso, num_fac, estado_fac) VALUES ('$fac', '$temp', '$ingreso', '$fact', '$esta')";

$resultado= mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

Comment: No queda claro cual es el problema. Seria mucho mas facil de entenser si nos aportaras los create de las tablas con: `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla` | Aparentemente sin distingir muy bien las relaciones, el orden de los insert deberia ser `ingresos`, `facturacion` y `certificado`

Comment: @Xerif Muchas gracias por responder agrego lo solicitado. En su respectivo orden como comentas .. las reglas serian: la persona Ingresa, se factura el ingreso, esa factura genera un código de facturación y luego se genera un certificado a ese ingreso con ese código de factura.

Comment: @A.Cedano será que así se logra entender un poco mas ??

Comment: Ahora se entiende mejor. Y, ¿qué es lo que ocurre, que muestra este mensaje:   *`El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitido`*? Haz un `print_r($_POST);` para ver si los datos se están recibiendo bien.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo logro imprimir en pantalla con el echo $insertar pero no me guarda en la la tabla factura.

Comment: Captura el mensaje de error y te dirá a qué se debe que no funcione. Lo puedes imprimir en esta parte: `if(!$resultado)
{
      echo "El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitido. El error ocurrido es: ".$mysqli->error;  //resto del código`  Agrega eso al mensaje y comenta el error que imprime.

Comment: @A.Cedano INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, cliente, oingreso, num_fac, estado_fac) VALUES (2,'dgsdggdssdgsdg', 4444,5555,PENDIENTE)
Array ( [ingreso_cod] => 2 [cliente] => dgsdggdssdgsdg [oingreso] => 4444 [num_fac] => 5555 [estado_fac] => PENDIENTE ) El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitidoUnknown column 'PENDIENTE' in 'field list'

Comment: La última columna es `VARCHAR` y tú no estás rodeando ese valor por comillas simples, por lo que el manejador confunde el valor con un nombre de columna. Prueba a rodear ese valor por comillas simples así: `$insertar = "INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, cliente, oingreso, num_fac, estado_fac) VALUES (".$_POST['ingreso_cod']. ",'".$_POST['cliente']. "', ".$_POST['oingreso'].",".$_POST['num_fac'].","'.$_POST['estado_fac'].'")";` De todos modos hay que mejorar tu código, aplicando consultas preparadas. Cuando me confirmes que así funciona, entonces te escribo una respuesta con código seguro.

Comment: @A.Cedano Intente hacer y nada tome el código que muy amablemente me corrigió pero aparece como error, estoy intentando de una y otra manera .. Ya comento.

Comment: Di el error que aparece ahora.

Comment: @A.Cedano Super bien por fin me logró ingresar los datos sin problemas, gracias por este sitio y por personas como usted que nos ayudan. Aqui dejo el código para otro compañero que le pueda servir de guía.
$insertar = "INSERT INTO facturacion (ingreso_cod, cliente, oingreso, num_fac, estado_fac) VALUES (" . $_POST['ingreso_cod'] . " , ' ".$_POST['cliente']. " ', " . $_POST['oingreso'] . " ,  " .$_POST['num_fac']  . " , ' " . $_POST['estado_fac'] . " ')";

Comment: No no, no cantes victoria. Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Conviene en este código aplicar consultas preparadas, de modo que ninguna de las variables del POST sean manipuladas para colarte alguna consulta maliciosa. Es extremadamente fácil que alguien amañe el código para borrar todas tus tablas por ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Aqui Atento para ..
Cuando me confirmes que así funciona, entonces te escribo una respuesta con código seguro

Comment: Bien bien. Escribiendo respuesta... escribiendo respuesta... espere por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a lo comentado, te dejo esta respuesta la cual consiste en lo siguiente:

- Dar seguridad al código aplicando consultas preparadas. En las partes esenciales comento dentro del mismo código cómo funcionan.
- Recoger adecuadamente los valores pasados por POST. Aquí he usado ternarios para asignar `NULL` cuando algún dato no exista en el POST. Tú puedes cambiar `NULL` por otro valor, como una cadena vacía, sobre todo en los campos que no admitan `NULL`.
- Aplicar un estilo de código *controlado* que consiste simplemente en ir recogiendo en un array las eventualidades del código. Cuando hay éxito se graba una clave `mensaje` en el array con un mensaje adecuado. Cuando hay error se graba una clave `error` en el array con el mensaje de error. Al final sólo imprimo el array, pero se puede usar de otra forma para determinar el status del código, si fue exitoso o erróneo.

Eso es lo esencial. Espero te sirva. Si no entiendes algo, lo puedes decir en comentarios.

```
<?php 
    require("conect.php");
    $conexion = new mysqli($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);
    $arrResult=array();
    if(!$conexion){
        $arrResult['error'] = "No lograste conectarte ! VERIFICA";
    }else{
        $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
        /*
            Se deben verificar las variables pasadas en el POST
            a mi me gusta esta técnica en la cual se usa un operador ternario
            para hacer la evaluación 
            y asignar NULL (puede ser otro valor como una cadena vacía)
            cuando el dato no esté en el POST
            Si por ejemplo hay una o varias columnas que nunca pueden ser NULL,
            entonces nosotros podemos controlar que el insert no se haga
            poniendo un if ($columnaX && $columnaY) {  ....
        */

        $ingreso_cod=(!empty($_POST['ingreso_cod'])) ?   $_POST['ingreso_cod'] : NULL;
        $cliente    =(!empty($_POST['cliente']))     ?   $_POST['cliente']     : NULL;
        $oingreso   =(!empty($_POST['oingreso']))    ?   $_POST['oingreso']    : NULL;
        $num_fac    =(!empty($_POST['num_fac']))     ?   $_POST['num_fac']     : NULL;
        $estado_fac =(!empty($_POST['estado_fac']))  ?   $_POST['estado_fac']  : NULL;

        /*
            Las consultas preparadas constan de dos partes
            la 1ª es la consulta en sí, a la cual no se le escriben los valores
            pues ese es el peligro de la Inyección.
            En lugar de los valores de ponen marcadores ?
        */
        $strSQL =  "INSERT INTO facturacion (
                                                ingreso_cod, 
                                                cliente, 
                                                oingreso, 
                                                num_fac, 
                                                estado_fac
                                            )
                                    VALUES   (  ?,?,?,?,?  )";


        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($strSQL);

        /*
            Esta es la 2ª parte importante, aquí se pasan los valores
            y el manejador elimina cualquier inyección
            Hay dos grupos de parámetros que se pasan en bind_param
            - el 1º son letras como "isiis", ahí cada inicial indica el tipo
              de dato que es cada columna (i)nteger o (s)tring...
              el orden de letras es el que corresponde a cada columna como están puestas
              más arriba en $strSQL
            - el 2º son los valores correspondientes a cada columna,
              pasados a través de las variables que ya recogimos en el POST
        */
        $stmt->bind_param("isiis",$ingreso_cod,$cliente,$oingreso,$num_fac,$estado_fac);

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
              $arrResult['error'] = "El Ingreso de factura que desea realizar no es permitido. ".$conexion->error;
        }else{
            /*Esto es sólo un gadget :) */
            $totalInsert=$stmt->affected_rows;  
            $mensaje=($totalInsert > 0) ? "Se ha insertado correctamente" : "No fue posible la inserción. Error: ".$stmt->error;  
            $arrResult['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Genera el siguiente error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function bind_param() in line 55

Comment: Sí, error mío, debe ser así: **`$stmt->bind_param("isiis",$ingreso_cod,$cliente,$oingreso,$num_fac,$estado_fac);`**

Comment: Excelente... todo guarda de manera correcta.